# Как конвертировать массив char в изображение формата jpeg с помощью libjpeg в С++

Tags: c++

Я передаю jpg файл по сокету,  в связи с этим у меня есть массив char (char*), который я получил от сокета и мне нужно обратно конвертировать этот массив в изображение формата jpeg? Как это сделать? Как я понимаю без библиотеки libjpeg мне это не сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если ты полностью передаешь файл jpg в сокет, то у тебя уже есть изображение в char* как поток, так что просто сохраняй весь массив в файл и PROFIT. А так лучше уточни вопрос он не полностью открывает вопрос

Comment: ну так то да, но я не знаю всех тонкостей, просто понятия не имею как это повлияет на jpg файл. Допустим andorid клиент написанный на java  отослал изображение в виде масива байтов, я получил его в виде масива char* и сохранил без расширения в какой-то файл, испортится ли файл если я считаю массив char и отдам обратно клиенту через сокет?

Comment: Если TCP сокет то файлы не изменяться во время отправки, если ты сохранишь без изменения то тоже все ок ты даже их можешь открыть и посмотреть

Comment: А если какой-нибудь другой протокол?

Comment: Но может данные измениться при отправки но если ты сделаешь какой-нить систему обнаружения ошибок и исправления то данные не будут изменятся, по подобному работают многие протоколы VPN, все протоколы которые построенные на TCP(http, ftp, ssh тысяччи их) то они данные тоже гарантировано не будут изменены из за отправки

Comment: я использую асинхронные советы, я просто хз, меняются ли данные до отправки при асинхронных сокетах?

Comment: Какой протокол на ассинхроном сокете, если tcp все ок

Comment: Если данные меняются при передаче, то это уже неработоспособность кода, а не особенности протоколов обмена.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто записать в файл для примера написал небольшой кусок кода который отлично работает:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ifstream file( "jpeg.jpeg", ios::binary );
  if (!file)
  {
     cerr << "can't open file's" << endl;
     return 0;
  }
  file.seekg(0,ios::end);
  size_t fSize = (int)file.tellg();
  unsigned char * a = new unsigned char[fSize];

  if (file.read( (char*)a,fSize ))
  {
    ofstream fout ( "def.jpeg", ios::binary );
    if (!fout)
       return 0;
    fout.write( (char*)a, fSize )
  }
  return 0;
}
```